# How to dinamically add values to the Y axis on LiveChart with WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, livecharts

I'm building a software with communicates with an arduino and the [livechart](https://lvcharts.net/) library.

On my software I have a singleton class that handles the communication with arduino and deliver the data to the graphs. On the graph I have a thread that ask every second to the graph the data. But beyond the data that I got from the singleton I need to add a new Y axys to it.

The Y axis that I need to add to the graph didn't come from the singleton, but from the class itself as the data is how much seconds the graph is plotting data.

How can I do it?

Some information: I'm building the graph based on the [Basic Line Chart](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wf/Basic%20Line%20Chart) and the code is the same on it. Except that I change some of the layout, config (disabling auto-resize) and creating a thread to add points to the graph.

Comment: you need a second Y-axis for the additional data?

Comment: Yes, the data on the second axis will show how much time has passed since the graph was built

Comment: Show us your code, and the class where the data is.

Comment: As I sent this question here, I was reading the live chart documentation at the same time. And with [this](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Constant%20Changes). But thank you very much for the help

Comment: And I didn't have done a measureModel class so I cound't do it anyways. But to rewrite what I did wrong isn't hard